# Como posso verificar o final de uma variável?

Tags: javascript, variáveis

Gostaria de saber se há uma forma de verificar se uma variável termina com um valor determinado, por exemplo no meu caso "25" ou 75 (me referirei como 25, para ficar mais fácil), ou seja se a variável terminar em 25 o código é executado.

> obs.: Note que eu não gostaria de executar o código caso o final do
> valor for MULTIPLO de 25, mas sim, igual 25.

> obs. 2.0: Tentei deixar meu código o mais organizado possível, para
> que entendessem ele, mas basicamente, eu queria fazer com que caso
> após um 'setTimeout', se a posição x ou y (definidas como userdados.x
> e userdados.y, respectivamente) terminassem com '25' elas recebessem
> mais 25 de complemento, para que fossem atualizadas para um número com
> final 50 ou múltiplo de 100.

```js
const px = 'px';

//#region User
const type = ['Espadachim', 'Arqueiro', 'Assassino', 'Mago'];
var userdados = {
    obj: document.querySelector('#user'),
    x: 0,
    y: 0, 
    height: 50,
    width: 30, 
    color: 'black'
}
var statususer = {
    nome: '',
    type_i: 0,
    type: '',
    color: '',

    hp: 10,
    atk: 0,
    def: 0,
    vel: 0,
    sor: 0,
    hea: 0,
}
var type_user = {
    nom_1: 'Espadachim',
    color: 'greenyellow',
    atk_1: 5,
    def_1: 4,
    vel_1: 2,
    sor_1: 1,
    hea_1: 0,
    
    nom_2: 'Arqueiro',
    color: '#ADEAEA',
    atk_2: 2,
    def_2: 3,
    vel_2: 5,
    sor_2: 2,
    hea_2: 0,

    nom_3: 'Assassino',
    color: 'red',
    atk_3: 3,
    def_3: 5,
    vel_3: 4,
    sor_3: 0,
    hea_3: 0,

    nom_4: 'Mago',
    color: 'orange',
    atk_4: 4,
    def_4: 2,
    vel_4: 3,
    sor_4: 3,
    hea_4: 5
}
//#endregion

function atualPos(obj, position, x, y){
    obj.style.position = position;
    obj.style.left = x;
    obj.style.top = y;
}function definir(obj, height, width, color){
    obj.style.height = height;
    obj.style.width = width;
    obj.style.backgroundColor = color;
}
definir(userdados.obj, userdados.height + px, userdados.width + px, userdados.color);


function iniciar(){
    var dx = 0, dy = 0, vel = userdados.width/2, tmp;
    document.addEventListener('keydown', KeyDown);
    document.addEventListener('keyup', KeyUp);
    tmp = setInterval(enterFrame, 100/2);
    function KeyDown(){
        var key = event.keyCode;
        if(key == 37){
            dx = -1;
        }else if(key == 38){
            dy = -1;
        }else if(key == 39){
            dx = 1;
        }else if(key == 40){
            dy = 1;
        }
    }
    function KeyUp(){
        var key = event.keyCode;
        if(key == 37){
            dx = 0;
        }else if(key == 38){
            dy = 0;
        }else if(key == 39){
            dx = 0;
        }else if(key == 40){
            dy = 0;
        }
    }
    function enterFrame(){
        userdados.x += vel * dx;
        userdados.y += vel * dy;
        console.log(userdados.x, userdados.y)
        atualPos(userdados.obj, 'relative', userdados.x + px, userdados.y + px);
    }
}
window.addEventListener('load', iniciar);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="link/style.css">
    <script src="link/script.js" defer></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="user"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não precisa recorrer a conversões de tipo, se o dado é um número inteiro e precisa extrair `n` dígitos, a partir da unidade, para comparar a um determinado valor basta obter o resto da divisão desse número inteiro por um potencia `10ⁿ`, onde `n` é a quantidade de dígitos a serem extraídos a partir da unidade.

Em javascript o resto da divisão é obtido com o [operador %](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Remainder).

Exemplo:
Encontrar os números naturais terminados com a dezena 25 no intervalo [0,1000]:

```js
//Para os naturais de [0, 1000] variando em i... 
for (let i = 0; i <= 1000; i++) {
  //Caso o resto da divisão de i por 10² seja 25 significa que o número i termina em 25.
  if (i % 100 == 25) {
    console.log("Final 25: %d", i);
  }
}
```

Exemplo:
Encontrar os números naturais terminados com a centena 278 no intervalo [0,10000]:

```js
//Para os naturais de [0, 10000] variando em i... 
for (let i = 0; i <= 10000; i++) {
  //Caso o resto da divisão de i por 10³ seja 278 significa que o número i termina em 278.
  if (i % 1000 == 278) {
    console.log("Final 278: %d", i);
  }
}
```

Exemplo:
Encontrar os números naturais terminados com a centena 001 no intervalo [0,10000]:

```js
//Para os naturais de [0, 10000] variando em i... 
for (let i = 0; i <= 10000; i++) {
  //Nesse caso somente os números i maiores que 1000 atendem a condição do resto da divisão de i por 10³ ser 001(zero a esquerda é suprimido).
  if (i > 1000 && i % 1000 == 1) {
    console.log("Final 001: %d", i);
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Existe uma forma que talvez possa ser considerada gambiarra mas é algo bem simples de ser entendido e de fazer funcionar.

Basta você transformar seu número em uma string e comparar os dois últimos dígitos com os 25 que você deseja.

```
function doisDigitosFinaisIgualVinteCinco(variavel) {
   //pegar tamanho de caractéres da variável
   const tamanhoVariavel = variavel.toString().length

   //pegar 2 últimos dígitos da variável e transformar em número novamente
   const ultimosDoisDigitos = Number(variavel.toString().substring(tamanhoVariavel-2));

   //verificar se ela é igual a 25 (pode usar ternário ou if else normal)
   if(ultimosDoisDigitos === 25) {
      return true
   } else {
      return false
   }
}
```

A partir desse resultado, basta chamar a função passando sua variável e fazendo sua ação caso retorne true ou false.

```
if(doisDigitosFinaisIgualVinteCinco(userdados.x)) {
     userdados.x += 25
}
```

É possível incrementar a função e fazer toda a lógica dentro dela, vai da sua forma de codar.